# Format of "app_settings" argument on azurerm_app_services Terraform resource

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure

We are using Terraform to deploy Web Apps to Azure and want to move away from using the web.config for configuration settings.  I believe we can implement these at deployment time using the `app_settings` argument on the `azurerm_app_service` resource but trying to find examples of how it should be properly formatted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`app_settings`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/app_service.html#app_settings) is a key-value pair of App Settings for the App Service.

The format of it:

```
   app_settings {
     "SOME_KEY" = "some-value"
   }
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/master/examples/app-service/app.tf).

Comment: how do I assign 2 or more connectionStrings ?.

Comment: As per @Farandole's answer, it looks like an equals is needed after `app_settings`

Comment: And broken link

Comment: Look at the folder "examples" in the repo: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/tree/main/examples/app-service

Answer (score 5):

It is now with an **=**

```
app_settings = {
    "SOME_KEY" = "some-value"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to set the app setting keys without double quotes:

```
app_settings = {
  SOME_KEY = "some-value"
}
```